# Running functions using string name from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have an array that has a bunch of function names. I am not storing the function in an object.

```
for (i = 0; i < view_functions.length; i++) {
    view_functions[i]();
}
```

This doesn't work, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You can store the functions themselves?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string

Comment: If the array stores name strings, you cannot call those. Please post your complete code showing what `view_functions` is and where else the functions are defined.

Comment: the array is just the name of the functions. Ex. header, body, footer... So I want header(); to load.

Comment: My second example covers that. Magic strings and `eval` are all generally frowned upon though. If you are declaring the names in your code, the first example would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works, so perhaps the code that defines the functions isn't quite right. Here is a fully working example.

```js
function yep() {
     alert('Yep');
}

function again() {
    alert('Again');
}

var view_functions = [
    yep,
    again
];

for (var i = 0; i < view_functions.length; i++) {
    view_functions[i]();
}
```

If you wanted to get a bit of design help in your code, you could introduce a factory. This has the added benefit of making unknown function names explicit.

```js
function yep() {
     alert('Yep');
}

function again() {
    alert('Again');
}

function functionFactory(name) {
    switch (name) {
        case 'yep':
            return yep;
        case 'again':
            return again;
        default:
            throw `${name} not a known function in functionFactory`;
    }
}

var view_functions = [
    'yep',
    'again'
];


for (var i = 0; i < view_functions.length; i++) {
    var func = functionFactory(view_functions[i]);
    func();
}
```

If you only have string names, I recommend not using string names... but you could go full-evil and use `eval`...

```js
function yep() {
     alert('Yep');
}

function again() {
    alert('Again');
}

var view_functions = [
    'yep',
    'again'
];

for (var i = 0; i < view_functions.length; i++) {
    var n = view_functions[i] + '()';
    eval(n);
}
```

But why not store the actual functions in the array instead...

Comment: No idea why someone downvoted this. It does in fact work.

Comment: some people just like to down vote it seems this works fine

Comment: "I have an array that has a bunch of function names. I am not storing the function in an object." This doesn't actually answer the question asked.

Comment: What smarx said. lol...

Comment: Man, do not do the eval.... read the duplicate link with solutions....

Comment: @epascarello - the eval is not the problem with that solution, it is a symptom of the problem. The first solution is there as the "better way". Replacing `eval` with `window[name]()` does not make magic strings better.

Comment: but doing one of the solutions with the methods registered to an object is a lot better than eval.

Comment: @epascarello that was my motivation for supplying multiple alternatives, and highlighting the weakness of the third solution. `eval` is not the problem in the last example - it isn't nice, but there is a much more fundamental design problem (that will be discovered when someone improves the name of one of those functions).

Comment: My problem is that I can't store the function in an object because the function name is coming from the JSON which handles all the views. Because preloading views and having the functions launch inside the view doesnt actually preload the view... it's a weird predicament.

Comment: Hi Ryan, the second option covers that scenario, and de-couples your code from wherever that JSON comes from.